# Is the following function C1? Please check my answer

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

Let us consider the function:
$$ f(x,y) \,=\, (xy)^{\gamma} \,(x+y-2) $$
with gamma defined as
$$ \gamma = \begin{cases} 2 \quad \text{if} \quad x<y \\ 5 \quad \text{if} \quad x \geq y.\\ \end{cases} $$

Is this function continuously differentiable in the point (x,y) = (1,1) ?

My answer is yes.

The partial derivative $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} = (xy)^{\gamma}\biggl[ \gamma \frac{x+y-2}{x} +1 \biggr]$ evaluated at (1,1) does not depend on gamma. The same is true for $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$, and so the function $f(x,y)$ is C1 in (1,1). Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
f_x(1,1)&=&\lim_{h\to0}{h(1+h)^{\gamma}}\\
&=&0\\
f_y(1,1)&=&\lim_{h\to0}{h(1+h)^{\gamma}}\\
&=&0\\
\end{eqnarray}
It doesn't matter whether $x<y$ or not because $\lim_{h\to0^\pm}(1+h)^{\gamma}$ is $1^{5}$ or $1^2$ which is $1$.
Therefore the full derivative is:
\begin{eqnarray}
D_xf(1,1)&=&f_x(1,1)+f_y(1,1)D_xy(1,1)\\
&=&0\\
D_yf(1,1)&=&f_y(1,1)+f_x(1,1)D_yx(1,1)\\
&=&0
\end{eqnarray}
Given $D_xy$ and $D_yx$ exist at $(1,1)$.

Comment: I don't understand your notation. What is the difference between $f_x$ and $D_x f$ ?

Comment: $f_x$ is the partial derivative of $f$ wrt $x$, $D_xf$ is the full derivative of $f$ wrt $x$, as stated in the answer. It's just shorthand for $\frac{df}{dx}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ which we would use in the case of multivariable functions since $f'$ and $\dot{f}$ are ambiguous; we don't know whether the derivative is wrt $x$ or $y$ and are only used for full derivatives.

Comment: And $D_x y $ corresponds to $\frac{d y}{d x}$ ?  But y is not a function of x.  
The term $D_x y(1,1)$ is difficult to understand.

Comment: If $y$ is not a function of $x$ then $D_xf=f_x$. $D_xf=f_x+f_yD_xy$ is based on the chain and product rules. For example, let $y$ be a function of $x$ and $f$ be $xy^2+y+x$. Then, $D_xf=y^2+2xyD_xy+D_xy+1$. Notice that the sum of the derivatives of all terms is $D_xf$ and to take the derivative of a term we applied the product and chain rules: $D_xT=T_x+T_yD_xy$ for any term $T$ taking the sum of partial derivatives of the terms gives $f_x$ etc. If $y$ is not a function of $x$ then $y$ is a constant as $x$ changes so $D_xy=0$ and the equation for $D_xf=0$ still holds.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you!

Comment: Anytime, no worries :)